# Convert day number to full date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I searched a lot online and could not find it. I found just the opposite - date to day

For example: Day 221 ==>  09/08/2017

This query do from this date to day number:

```
SELECT DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, SYSDATETIME())
```

or

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) AS CHAR(4)) + '-01-01', GETDATE() + 1) AS number_of_today
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your reference point? Days from what? Days into the new year?

Comment: from this year ?  no ?

Comment: Is this has an specific year? until what date? today?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yet another option is with DateFromParts() and GetDate() for the current year

**Example**

```
Select DateAdd(DAY,221,DateFromParts(Year(GetDate())-1,12,31))
```

**Returns**

```
2017-08-09
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the date as it relates to January 1st, 1900:

```
SELECT
   dateadd(day, dayToConvert, 0)
FROM
   myTable
```

I think you can change it to base off of January 1st, 2017 by:

```
SELECT
   dateadd(day, dayToConvert, '2016-12-31')
FROM
   myTable
```

It is December 31st because you want to **add** that many days to the date in the third argument.

Answer (score 0):

The DATEADD function should work, as so:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day,221,someDate) AS someDate2 FROM sometable
```

[Docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql)

[Tutorial here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Stored Procedure Option:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_NUM_TO_DATE @NUM INT,@DATESTART DATE AS
BEGIN
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,@NUM ,DATEADD(Day,-1,@DATESTART))
END
GO
```

EXECUTE:

```
EXEC PROC_NUM_TO_DATE 221,'2017-01-01'
```

RESULT:

```
2017-08-09
```